# What is the best way to manage db connection in a preforking daemon

Tags: python, mysql, socketserver

I am pretty new to python and am using pythons SocketServer.ForkingTCPServer to create a network script that needs to connect to a database(mysql). I expect the program to get hit at around 30 - 40 times a second. Is it possible to share the same database connection across the processes?

```
import os
import SocketServer
import MySQLdb

class EchoHandler(SocketServer.StreamRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
                self.wfile.write("SET VARIABLE DBDIALSTRING dbstuff \n")
                self.wfile.flush()
                self.conn.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':


    conn = MySQLdb.connect (host = "10.0.0.12", user = "dbuser", passwd = "secert", db = "dbname")
    SocketServer.ForkingTCPServer.allow_reuse_address = 1
    server = SocketServer.ForkingTCPServer(('10.0.0.10', 4242), EchoHandler)
    print "Server listening on localhost:4242..."
    try:
        server.allow_reuse_address
        server.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print "\nbailing..."
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. For example this http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html is/can be thread safe. You can connect before starting forks and than use global variable. It's not pretty but will work.

You can pass connection as a  parameter to constructor.
It will be better if you paste some code in  question.

Comment: Thanks! That pretty much answers my question, now I just have to figure out how to pass it into my class :) As suggested I posted the code.